# Migration assistant won't let me use an umlaut in the password for the encrypted time machine backup

Tags: time-machine, password

I'm trying to restore a mac from a time machine backup. The time machine backup is found but requires a password and it happens to include one of those funny letters with an accent. The usual way to type those letters would be with <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>u</kbd> and the character you want the dots above, e.g. `a`. But when I click the <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>u</kbd> key I hear an error sound and no new character is added to the password field. Even ignoring that the password won't work as it likely doesn't write it out properly. I can't copy past things, there is no accessibility keyboard... it seems I am unable to write my password...

Any way I can solve this at all?

I tried typing the password into the username field in an earlier screen and copy it but the clipboard is empty or pasting is disabled in the password field here.

I also don't think you can remove/change passwords from encrypted backups even if you have the password?

Can I restore the computer with something other than the migration assistant?

[image]

Comment: What is your keyboard language and the actual keyboard layout set to? I am no expert but you should definitely be able to change it to something like German which includes `ä`, `ü` and `ö`.

Comment: Maybe there are other ways to generate the character ü .  Try them all.  Can you paste into that password field?

Comment: @X_841 the physical layout of my laptop keyboard is English. I don't know where those keys would be if I changed the layout to German?

Comment: @GEdgar I have tried all I could find and there is no pasting at all in that field :(

Comment: Apple does show all the keyboard layouts, so you could set your machine to the german layout then use the correct keys for the password looking at the relevant layout.

Comment: Just to add - if you can't get this to work then set up the computer blank and change the password after booting, then reset and restore.

Comment: See if you can copy/paste using right click. Sometimes you can't Cmd/C Cmd/V but right click copy then right click paste does work. Alternatively, if you switch to German keyboard layout ü is to the right of p, ö & ä are just below

Comment: There is no right click or at least not working...

Comment: …and what happens with the second of the **two** suggestions I made?

Comment: I appreciate all your suggestions @Tetsujin. I was unable to change the keyboard layout and found out for me to do that I would have to reinstall the machine from scratch which is not what I wanted. So I ended up making a new backup from the the machine that is broken but intermittendly boots without an encryption key and after several failures it ended up working and it circumvented the issue. Crazy that specific characters don't work as passwords.